# Change the AWS given domain for my static website to a godaddy domain

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, web, dns

Recently, I created a static website in React.js and uploaded it on AWS.

I got the following domain for it: [MontgomeryHacks](http://montgomeryhacks.com.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/) (http://montgomeryhacks.com.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/)

I want to change that domain to www.montgomeryhacks.com which I bought on GoDaddy. 
Is there any way to do that.

Comment: https://www.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/DNS-should-point-to-a-AWS-S3-hosted-page/td-p/137295

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not about programming. Try webmasters SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CNAME.

Under Godaddy DNS settings make just one entry, set Host WWW CNAME, points to, "montgomeryhacks.com.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/"

The last step under Forwarding/manage is to "forward only" your naked domain name "montgomeryhacks.com" to "www.montgomeryhacks.com"

If you did it right your browser will display your site as "wwwmontgomeryhacks.com" whether you entered the www or not when you entered the url.

Be sure to wait at least 30 minutes before testing your changes and by all means clear your cache in your browser and you local DNS cache or it will use the old address that it remembers from the past.

Comment: Yep it worked, thanks!